# Keras, DNN ending with sigmoid - model.predict produces values < 0.5. This indicates...?

Tags: keras

I'm trying a simple Keras project with Dense layers for binary classification. About 300000 rows of data, labels are

```
training_set['TARGET'].value_counts()    
0    282686
1     24825
```

My model looks like this

```
def build_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),
                           input_shape=(train_data.shape[1],)))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(32, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

So it's binary classification that ends with a sigmoid. It's my understanding that I should get values close to 0 or close to 1? I've tried different model architectures, hyperparameters, epochs, batch sizes,  etc. but when I run model.predict on my validation set my values never get above 0.5. Here are some samples.

```
20 epochs, 16384 batch size
max 0.458850622177124,  min 0.1022530049085617
max 0.47131556272506714,  min 0.057787925004959106 

20 epochs, 8192 batch size
max 0.42957592010498047,  min 0.060324762016534805
max 0.3811708390712738,  min 0.022215187549591064

20 epochs, 4096 batch size
max 0.3163970410823822,  min 0.0657803937792778 

20 epochs, 2048 batch size
max 0.21799422800540924,  min 0.03832605481147766
```

Is this an indication that I'm doing something wrong?

Training and validation loss
[image]

Answer (score 0):

<s>I think the dropout is a bit high and if it's a binary classification, then why in the end a single node?</s>

It's absolutely okay to use sigmoid for binary classification. So the answer provided below isn't apt.

<s>Make sure your target variable is having proper shape in case of softmax...(one hot/ `to_categorical()`)</s>

```
def build_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),
                           input_shape=(train_data.shape[1],)))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(layers.Dense(32, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(layers.Dense(**num_classes**, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model
```

To improve it further, you need to use some techniques, such as cross-validation, batch normalization, and increase the epochs(maybe).

Comment: Short answer, I end with a single node because this is basically my first deep learning project and Chollet's "Deep Learning with Python" ended its binary classification project with that layer.
I thought binary classifications were one node with sigmoid, and multiclass was n nodes with softmax?

Comment: The quick Dropout change didn't make a difference. I added a typical training and validation loss pic in the hopes that it offers a clue. I'll try the other suggestions, thanks.

Comment: How are you passing your inputs/any preprocessing then? Add that and the compiling step.. Will help others to debug easily as I don't think there's anything wrong with the model building process except that I prefer softmax one as it lets me know model's behaviour...

Comment: Numeric columns are being subtracted by the mean and divided by the std.
Categorical columns (M/F etc.) are being one-hot encoded using pd.get_dummies.

Comment: Drop a sample of your data if it's too big! I will try experiments!

Comment: I'm using the Kaggle competition "home credit default risk" for my data.

Comment: @Aditya We do not use `softmax` for binary classification tasks. It is used in the case of multiclass classification. In this case the SO is right to use `sigmoid` with 1 output neuron.

Comment: Yes, the OP is correct definitely. Sigmoid is sufficient for a single output neuron node.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the previous answer, I would say that your output layer configuration is correct although I agree with the previous answer regarding your dropout being too high. A dropout of 0.5 will mean that 50% if your neurons will be dropped so basically you are dropping half your neurons in the layer which in turn means that your model will not be able to learn much.

Another point I would like to mention is that you should use `adam` as your optimizer as it gives a better result most of the times.

In short to improve your accuracy, do Hyperparameter tuning for things like **no of layers**, **no of neurons**, **optimizer**, **learning rate**, **activation function**, **batch size**, **epochs** etc. Use `RandomizedSearchCV` for this purpose.